# Application fails when free memory is low but available memory is high

Tags: linux, memory, sisense

I am building data models via an app called Sisense on Linux.  Lately the process fails with an out of memory error. Running `free -h` I see that that the failure occurs when free memory is low, but before it actually reaches zero and even though there is still plenty of available memory.

Here is the exception:

```
Failed to build custom table: Rule_pre; BE#521691 SQL error: SafeModeException:
Safe-Mode triggered due to memory pressure. Pod physical memory: 5.31 GB available, 2.87 GB 
used, 8.19 GB total. Server physical memory: 4.86 GB available, 28.67 GB used, 
33.54 GB total. Application total virtual memory: 2.54 GB. The server exceeded 85% capacity 
(28.67/33.54). Possible ways to reduce memory pressure: increase server memory, adjust data 
modelling (M2M, un-indexed string fields, etc.), reduce number of simultaneous queries
```

And here is the output of `free -h` where you can see the declining memory in the center "free" column. Once free memory got below 235 MB I saw the above exception.

[image: Here is the memory usage per the linux util "free"]

The free util man page has these definitions for free and available memory:

> **free**   Unused memory (MemFree and SwapFree in /proc/meminfo)
>
> **available**
> Estimation of how much memory is available for starting new applications, without swapping. Unlike the data provided by the cache or free  fields,  this  field  takes  into account  page cache  and  also that not all reclaimable memory slabs will be reclaimed due to items being in use (MemAvailable in /proc/meminfo, available on kernels 3.14, emulated on kernels 2.6.27+, otherwise the same as free

As I read on the internet there seems to be a casualness about low free memory. That it is not an issue. But the failure coincides with free memory getting to low. If I understand the man page, the available memory is for starting new applications. I am assuming then that available memory is not available to the existing application that fails, and that free memory is indeed what matters. But any confirmation form others or additional explanation would be appreciated.  I'd also be curious about opinions on whether this may constitute a memory leak or if I should simply allocate more memory somehow perhaps at the Linux layer.

Comment: Note that the error message suggests that the error is triggered before memory is completely exhausted: "Safe-Mode triggered due to memory pressure... The server exceeded 85% capacity (28.67/33.54)."

Comment: @JohnKugelman Does that mean the "free -h" output is not relevant? Or are you simply noting how the application's memory  threshold of 85% should be highlighted in this post? I am trying to understand if and how the free memory relates to the exception.  If the threshold of 85% did not exist would the error would simply occur at 100% and would that be shown in the free column as zero free despite there being plenty of available memory? I find this very confusing.

Comment: Actually I see you edited the post and are offering explanation of that. Got it.

Comment: Which versions is your sisense? Did you see [this](https://documentation.sisense.com/latest/linux/linuxrn.htm#gsc.tab=0)? Specifically check the page for `BE#521691` ...

Comment: yes I saw this. I have version 8.2.6.4 which should include the fix. But the error still happens. I have a case open with sisense and was not expecting a specific solution here. My real question, is the difference between, and impact of, free memory vs available memory as shown by the linux utility 'free'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have enough understanding here. Free memory never goes below 200MB whether a build fails or succeed. It does not appear to be an indicator of the issue. A successful build will also show a drop in free memory to 200MB.